# How to Create a Flagging Column Based on The Maximum Value Of a Feature ID?

Tags: sql, sas, conditional-statements, flags

I have This DataSet:

```
 data test;
 input Feature_ID Client_ID;
 cards;
 52004 541111
 56222 541111
 56300 541111
 73222 980002 
 73600 980002
 78006 980002
 85000 980002
 95001 1000001
 98020 1000001
 ;
 run;
```

And I want to Create a Flag Column , That Takes 1 for the Maximum Feature_ID for Each Client .

The Result Should be as follow:

```
 data test;
 input Feature_ID Client_ID Flag;
 cards;
 52004 541111 0
 56222 541111 0
 56300 541111 1
 73222 980002 0
 73600 980002 0
 78006 980002 0
 85000 980002 1
 95001 1000001 0
 98020 1000001 1
 ;
 run;
```

How Can I do it?

What I've done (Because the Original Data was not ordered), I started by ordering the Data, using Proc SQL, This Way:

```
 proc sql;
     create table tab_Trial as select
           Feature_ID
          ,Client_ID
       from Test
       order by Feature_ID, Client_ID;
  quit;
```

And Then Tried this Code, to Create the Flag Column

```
 data Flagging; 
    set Tab_Trial;
    by Client_ID; 
    if Last.Feature_ID = 1 then Flag = 1;
    else Flag = 0;
 run;
```

But I got a Column ***Flag*** filled with 0.
any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [last.variable](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2018/02/26/how-to-use-first-variable-and-last-variable-in-a-by-group-analysis-in-sas.html), but firstly, sort the dataset:

```
data test;
 input Feature_ID Client_ID;
 cards;
 52004 541111
 56300 541111
 56222 541111
 73222 980002 
 73600 980002
 85000 980002
 78006 980002
 98020 1000001
 95001 1000001
 ;
 run;


 proc sort data=test out=test_sorted;
 by Client_ID Feature_ID;
 quit;


 data test1;
   set test_sorted;
   by Client_ID Feature_ID;
   if last.Client_Id then flag=1;
   else flag=0;
 run;
```

**INPUT:**

```
+------------+-----------+
| Feature_ID | Client_ID |
+------------+-----------+
|      52004 |    541111 |
|      56300 |    541111 |
|      56222 |    541111 |
|      73222 |    980002 |
|      73600 |    980002 |
|      85000 |    980002 |
|      78006 |    980002 |
|      98020 |   1000001 |
|      95001 |   1000001 |
+------------+-----------+
```

**Sorted dataset:**

```
+------------+-----------+
| Feature_ID | Client_ID |
+------------+-----------+
|      52004 |    541111 |
|      56222 |    541111 |
|      56300 |    541111 |
|      73222 |    980002 |
|      73600 |    980002 |
|      78006 |    980002 |
|      85000 |    980002 |
|      95001 |   1000001 |
|      98020 |   1000001 |
+------------+-----------+
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
+------------+-----------+------+
| Feature_ID | Client_ID | flag |
+------------+-----------+------+
|      52004 |    541111 |    0 |
|      56222 |    541111 |    0 |
|      56300 |    541111 |    1 |
|      73222 |    980002 |    0 |
|      73600 |    980002 |    0 |
|      78006 |    980002 |    0 |
|      85000 |    980002 |    1 |
|      95001 |   1000001 |    0 |
|      98020 |   1000001 |    1 |
+------------+-----------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you  ,Indeed , now i see my Error.

Answer (score 1):

No further sorting is needed if your dataset is already sorted by `client_id` - you can use a double DOW-loop:

```
data have;
input Feature_ID Client_ID;
cards;
52004 541111
56222 541111
56300 541111
73222 980002 
73600 980002
78006 980002
85000 980002
95001 1000001
98020 1000001
;
run;

data want;
do _n_ = 1 by 1 until(last.client_id);
  set have;
  by client_id;
  max_feature_id = max(feature_id,max_feature_id);
end;
do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
  set have;
  flag = feature_id = max_feature_id;
  output;
end;
drop max_feature_id;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

In proc sql, you can use `GROUP BY` to get the maximum feature id and then `case` logic to assign the flag:

```
proc sql;
    create table tab_Trial as
        select Feature_ID, Client_ID,
               (case when Feature_ID = max_Feature_ID then 1 else 0 end) as flag
       from Test t join
            (select Client_ID, max(Feature_ID) as max_Feature_ID
             from Test t
             group by Client_ID
            ) tc
            on tc.Client_ID = t.Client_ID
       order by Feature_ID, Client_ID;
  quit;
```